# How to add documentation to attribute of composite component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, documentation, composite-component

I have a composite component that looks something like this:

```
<composite:interface>           
    <composite:attribute name="confirmUnload" type="java.lang.Boolean" default="false" />
    <composite:attribute name="showLoader" type="java.lang.Boolean" default="true" />
    <composite:attribute title="test test" name="menuFormIds" type="java.lang.String" default="menuForm" />
    <composite:attribute name="unloadMessage" type="java.lang.String" default="You have unsaved data" />            
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <div title="unloadEventComponent">...</div>
</composite:implementation>
```

When using this component in a page, eclipse autocomplete will help out with the attributes. However, sometimes it's difficult to understand what the attribute does without looking at the code, which does not help the user experience.

Is there any way to have attribute descriptions added to a composite component in a way that it shows up in eclipse autocomplete?

PrimeFaces components usually have descriptions when selecting an attribute, but they use custom components instead of composites.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For that, the `shortDescription` attribute should be used. E.g.

```html
<composite:attribute name="confirmUnload" type="java.lang.Boolean" default="false" 
    shortDescription="Set to true to enable the confirm unload message. Defaults to false." />
```